# php simplehtmldom issue

Tags: php

I have a question on simplehtmldom.
how can I get a text of certain element that is a next_sibling of another element that contains a certain text?

for example:

I have html text as this:

```
<div>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>prova</td>
   <td>pippo</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

and I need to extract the text of second "td".Consider that I know that the value "prova" is a fixed value. I thought that i could use this code:

```
echo $html->find("td:contains('prova')",0)->next_sibling();
```

but "contains" doesn't exists in simplehtmldom. 
How I can do that?

Thanks a lot

---

thanks for your answer but I need to extract text of **td** next to **td** that contains the text "prova".

As example I need to extract the value "pippo" with a similar code

```
echo $html->find("td:contains('prova')",0)->next_sibling()->innertext;
```

because I know the value of first column. Unfortunately the function **contains** doesn't exists in simplehtmldom.

The code

```
echo $html->find("td:innertext('prova')",0)->next_sibling();
```

doesn't is the right way.

Do you have other suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<?php
include_once "simple_html_dom.php";
// the html code loaded (in this case in string mode)
$html = '<div>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>prova</td>
   <td>pippo</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>';

$dom = str_get_html($html);
// the selector :contains isn't develop yet
$tds = $dom -> find("td");
foreach($tds as $td){
    if ($td -> innertext == "prova"){
        echo $td -> next_sibling()  -> innertext;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi biancardi, 
I know that i can use foreach oh TDs elements but I would like know if exists a contain function similar jquery.

Thanks for your answer.